# Regular Expression with Condition judgement in .NET

Tags: regex

```
private static Regex regex_Unsigned_Integer = new Regex("^(([0-9]{1})|([1-9][0-9]+))$");
private static Regex regex_Signed_Integer = new Regex("^([+|-]?)(([0-9]{1})|([1-9][0-9]+))$");
private static Regex regex_Unsigned_Factor = new Regex("^(([0-9]+[/][1-9]{1}[0-9]*)|([1-9]{1}[0-9]*['][1-9]+[/][1-9]{1}[0-9]*))$");
private static Regex regex_Signed_Factor = new Regex("^([+|-]?)(([0-9]+[/][1-9]{1}[0-9]*)|([1-9]{1}[0-9]*['][1-9]+[/][1-9]{1}[0-9]*))$");
private static Regex regex_Unsigned_Decimal = new Regex("^((([0-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-9]+))[.][0-9]+)$");
private static Regex regex_Signed_Decimal = new Regex("^([+|-]?)((([0-9]{1})|([1-9]{1}[0-9]+))[.][0-9]+)$");
```

1. I'd like to Match Some Number with Regular Expression, such as (-1), (-1.3), 1'3/7, (+3), 3;
2. However, it contains a sepcial condition that only signed number should be   surrounded with bracket;
3. Illegde string : (3), -3, +1'3/7
4. Correct string : 3, (-3), (+1'3/7)
5. Therefore, I have to construct 6 Regex in .NET as followed:
6. Does Regular Expression contains some rules to match the condition that only signed number should be surrounded with bracket.
7. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* 6 regexes, all of this can fit in a single one:

```
^(?:
  (?<sign>\([-+])?
    (?:[0-9]+')?
    [0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?
    (?:/[0-9]+(?:.[0-9]+)?)?
  (?(sign)\))
)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kP4fI9/1)

The part you were asking for is this:

- Capture a `(` followed by `+` or `-` in an optional named group:

  ```
  (?<sign>\([-+])?
  ```
- Match the number: it's the middle part of the regex
- If the `sign` group matched, then match a `)`:

  ```
  (?(sign)\))
  ```

  This is the conditional regex operator you were looking for:

  ```
  (?(groupName)thenExpression|elseExpression)
  ```

  The `|elseExpression` part is optional.